# SQL Server - extra filegroups in backup

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to back up only a single secondary filegroup with

```
BACKUP DATABASE foo 
FILEGROUP = 'filegroup'
TO DISK '....'
```

When I look at the backup contents the primary filegroup and log file are also there, not just the secondary filegroup/file I asked for.

The DB is in 'simple' recovery mode and the secondary filegroup is marked read-only.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right. The primary file group will be present in every backup that you take. It's where system objects live and the information there will be necessary to do a restore. And log will also always be present (even if your db is in simple recovery) since SQL Server uses the transaction log to guarantee ACID compliance. TL;DR - everything is as it should be.